# Initializing controller instance with different data sets in angular

Tags: angularjs, initialization

How can I use a different sets of initialization variables for each instance of controller in my app?

in view:

```
<div ng-controller="showProjectList">
{{project_list}}<!--user 1-->
</div>

<div ng-controller="showProjectList">
{{project_list}}<!--user 2-->
</div>
```

in controller

```
myapp.controller('showProjectList',function($http)
{ $scope.project_list= <Here I have a http request with argument user_id to fetch project_list>
}
```

Now how do I initialize each controller with a different user_id? One solution I have readon stackexchange & on google-groups is the use of ng-init.(link google-grp: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/J6DE8evSOBg) .However the use of ng-init is cautioned against in the same threads. So how do you initialize a controller with data then ?

Comment: where is your list of user id's stored?

Comment: @Alp in the view: user_id needs to be passed into the controller scope from the view, so the controller instance generates a different list.

Comment: ok, i'll add a small modification to my answer then

Answer (score 1):

**You could use a combination of a controller, a directive and a service for that matter.**

The controller is holding the user id's.

The directive is rendering the project list.

The service is responsible for fetching the data from the server. You could implement a cache and/or use `$resource` in here.

---

Here is the template code:

```
<div ng-controller="Projects">
    <!-- here you can put an input element with
         ng-model="users" to modify the user list on the fly -->
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <project-list user="user" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
myapp.controller('Projects', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [1, 2, 3];
}]);
```

The directive:

```
myapp.directive('projectList', ['UserService', function(UserService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            user: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'project-list.html',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            UserService.getUserProject($scope.user).then(function(response) {
                $scope.userProjects = response;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

The service:

```
myapp.factory('UserService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var getUserProject = function(user) {
        var promise = $http.get('users/' + user + '/project');
        return promise;
    }

    return {
        getUserProject: getUserProject
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks I was thinking of a directive could be a way out. Let me see how this fits into what I'm looking for.